# Saving figures with matplotlib on NFS filesystem

Tags: python, matplotlib, nfs

I am using ipython notebook through Anaconda on RHEL 6.7. The machine is set up with an NFS storage; that is, `df -P -T /home/USERNAME | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}'` prints 'nfs'.

So I want to save matplotlib figures created in ipython notebooks. Calling the `savefig` function, however, gives me this error (I have suppressed most of it):

```
RuntimeError: dvipng was not able to process the following file:
/home/USERNAME/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/3007d273a0b2642aa3abce6d3d640283.dvi
Here is the full report generated by dvipng: 

No dvipng error report available.
```

My suspicion is that this has to do with NFS (since it has given me other problems in the past) but otherwise I don't really know where to go from here. Any help greatly appreciated, and please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: Looking further at this issue, Cong Ma may be right about NFS being innocent. I am saving figures with LateX rendering, and the LateX installation on this machine appears to be broken. I'll see if I can't fix this problem by fixing that one.

Comment: Confirmed to be an issue with LateX rendering. Make sure your packages are up to date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem occurs here in an up-to-date OpenSuse Leap VM with an also up-to-date stack of Anaconda. To my dismay it is not deterministic: batch generating plots fails at very different datasets. It helped to insert a

```
time.sleep(5)
```

and now the problem occurs much less frequently. Still a PITA though.

Answer (score 1):

This may not strictly be a problem of NFS.

Looking at its [source in this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3f758abfa1ac9495561dc851a710709f614df29f/lib/matplotlib/texmanager.py#L521) and [this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3f758abfa1ac9495561dc851a710709f614df29f/lib/matplotlib/texmanager.py#L552) (note that here is an error: It should have said `"dvips failed"`, not `"dvipng"`), it seems that the external command with `dvipng` or `dvips` failed.

So there are many possibilities.  First you need to figure out which external program was being `system()`ed.  Then, maybe you need to check whether this command could be found in `PATH` environment variable at all, or whether the file itself is crashing that command.  Try running `dvip(ng|s)` manually on that file and see if you can get an error report.

BTW, from the linked source, if I read the source correctly (IIRTSC), I don't think the `matplotlib` library is doing the right thing to catch an error report by capturing the `stdout` of `dvip(ng|s)` command.  And we know `os.system()` is evil ...

Answer (score 0):

Without properly maintained LateX packages, matplotlib (at least running through a Jupyter notebook) apparently is unable to save LateX-formatted plots, even if they display correctly.